# Why does having GROUP BY in an IN clause cause the query to become unexecutable?

Tags: sql, mysql, group-by, dolphindb

```
SELECT id, user_id, item_id
FROM questionnaire_answer_old_0
WHERE item_id IN (
    SELECT item_id
    FROM questionnaire_answer_old_0
    GROUP BY user_id, item_id
    HAVING COUNT(user_id) > 1 AND COUNT(item_id) > 1
);
```

The code provided above executes the subquery normally. The issue arises when attempting to run the entire query, which results in no response and no error messages; it just shows as 'query in progress.' Removing the GROUP BY from the subquery allows the query to execute normally. What could be the reason for this?

Comment: It could be that execution of the entire query is taking a long time.  It could also be some kind of bug in MySQL Workbench, if you're using that.

Comment: Is the MySQL server process consuming any CPU?

Comment: 1) Replace WHERE IN with INNER JOIN. 2) Your query is excess. `HAVING COUNT(*) > 1` is enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use window functions, which might be more efficient.

`HAVING COUNT(user_id) > 1 AND COUNT(item_id) > 1` probably doesn't do what you think it does, because `COUNT(someValue)` just counts the number of non-nulls, not the number of distinct values.

I've tried to guess your intention, it looks like you want to get all rows for an `item_id`, where any of those are part of a group of `item_id, user_id` where there are multiple rows. So you need two levels of partitioning.

```sql
SELECT id, user_id, item_id
FROM (
    SELECT
      *,
      COUNT(CASE WHEN count > 1 THEN 1 END) OVER (PARTITION BY user_id) AS hasCountGtThan1
    FROM (
        SELECT *,
          COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY user_id, item_id) AS count
        FROM questionnaire_answer_old_0 qa
    ) qa
) qa
WHERE hasCountGtThan1 > 0;
```

Comment: *`COUNT(CASE WHEN count > 1 THEN 1 END)`* may be replaced with `SUM(count > 1)` which will remove excess NULL check.